# XML documentation: using "cref" in <returns>, is this acceptable or not necessary?

Tags: .net, documentation, documentation-generation, xml-documentation, ghostdoc

I am using GhostDoc to document my methods etc... and its working well but it doesn't fill the `<returns>` ...

Can anyone tell me what i should be doing i.e

If it returns an object called "Roles" then

```
<returns>A role object see <see cref = "UserRole" /></returns>
```

or simply

```
<returns>A role object</returns>
```

or

```
<returns>A role</returns>
```

I know its sounds a bit being too precise but i want to start off correct :-)

Take for example a standard string return type of a username

```
<returns>The user name</returns>

<returns>The user name, see <see cref = "system.string" /> </returns>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your cues from MSDN ([example 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.getnamespace.aspx), [example 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx)):

```
<returns>A <see cref="string" /> that contains the username</returns>

<returns>An object that contains role information</returns>
```

A documentation generator will include the type of the return value, so it's not necessary to always included it; however, if it make sense (or you want to point it out) it's not a problem to do so, but probably in the flow the statement, rather than as a separate "see X" statement.